# Redefining within header files

Tags: c

I created a library, with a .h file and a .c file. I'm now getting that I am redefining my functions. I have the header guards...what else could be wrong?
[image]
Oh and this is in C

Comment: header guards go in the .h file

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow...Try to edit your question and add your code directly into the edit.  Also tell us what you expect :)

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. Also, [mcve]

Comment: I too cannot make heads nor tails. Not enough info

Comment: Headers should contain declarations.  Source files should contain definitions.  Don't put definitions into headers; don't put declarations into source files.

Comment: I really dislike looking into too narrow screenshots of code. So I won't tell you the problem you have with the spelling**S** of your header guard.

Comment: @FelixGuo I think it might actually be a header file, which would neither make it better, nor prevent the mentioned error. So you are right in both cases...

Answer (score 1):

Macro identifiers cannot contain dots, they must be composed from alphanumerics and underscores.

```
#ifndef Header.h_
```

should be

```
#ifndef Header_h
```

and also for `#define Header_h`.